# LISP. Create list of pairs

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have a code like below. It return list as `(((1 . 2) (1 . 0)) ((1 . 2) (1 . 1)) ((1 . 2) (1 . 3)) ((1 . 2) (1 . 4)) ((1 . 2) (1 . 5)) ((1 . 2) (1 . 6)) ((1 . 2) (1 . 7)) ((1 . 2) (0 . 2)) ((1 . 2) (2 . 2)))`

I wonder if I can rewrite generHod function in the way to make it return list like `((1.2 1.0) (3.4 4.2) (1.3 1.3)...)`

```
(setf hod '())

(defun generHod (CurrX CurrY)
    (dotimes (y 8)
        (if (/= y CurrY)
            (setf hod (append hod (list (append (list (cons CurrX CurrY))(list (cons CurrX y))))))
        )
    )

    (dotimes (x 8)
        (if (/= x CurrX)
            (setf hod (append hod (list (append (list (cons CurrX CurrY))(list (cons x CurrY))))))
        )
    )   

)
```

Comment: All these append operations: bad style.

Comment: What solution do you offer? Unfortunately, I'm not much aware about different lisp functions which can make it easier.

Comment: I can offer you a good and free for download introductory Lisp book, which explains the basics: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/index.html

Comment: Additionally, showing which parameters you used to get your result, and how the expected result would be derived from the current result would be most helpful.

Comment: Along with what others have said, the list you give as the expected answer has things like "1.2" and "1.0", which are interpreted in lisp as floating point numbers. The answer you're getting generates things like "(1 . 2)". This is a cons cell with 2 integers. You probably need to be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: (generHod 1 2)
Indeed it returns graph of all available round's steps in chosen square.

Comment: I want to create list which consists of lists  like (1.2 4.3) . And this list must be like ((1.2 3.4) (3.1 4.5)), but as you see every pair in list I create is bounded that i want to avoid

Comment: Ok, you should probably go and read something like chapter 12 of [PCL](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html). And possibly chapters 1-11 too if you're finding that one hard to follow.

Comment: Creating a float number from two integers isn't really hard. Actually it's totally easy.

Comment: Can you try to describe what this function is intended to return? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I made big mistake in forming question. "I wonder if I can rewrite generHod function in the way to make it return list like ((1.2 1.0) (3.4 4.2) (1.3 1.3)...)" - here I had to write ((1 . 2 1 . 0) (3 . 4 4 . 2) (1 . 3 1 . 3)...)

Comment: Is your issue the "style" in which this is printed? Then you're looking for `format` to do actual output (not the one of the REPL). You still don't say what you actually want this function to do.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
(setf hod '())
```

This is a bad way to define a global variable; try

```
(defparameter hod ())
```

But why use a global variable at all? The function can construct a new list and just return it. If the caller wants to stick it into a global variable, that's up to the caller; it's extraneous to the operation of the function.

```
(defun generHod ...)
```

The syntax `generHod` is not distinguished from `GENERHOD` or `generhod` in Common Lisp, under the default readtable. All those tokens produce the same symbol. It is best not to play mixed case games in Lisp identifiers; if you want multiple words, put in a dash like `gen-hod`.  Usually `generate` is abbreviated all the way to `gen` by English speaking hackers, not `gener`. See the `gensym` funtion in Common Lisp, for instance.

In your function, there is a completely superfluous `append`:

```
(append
  (list (cons CurrX CurrY)) 
  (list (cons CurrX y))))
```

The pattern `(append (list X0) (list X1) ... (list XN))` can be rewritten `(list X0 X1 ... XN)`.  You're making superfluous lists of things only to append them together to make one list, instead of just listing the things in the first place.

To get the values from integer to floating point, the `float` function can be used, and the `loop` macro provides an idiom for iterating and collecting items:

```
(defun gen-hod (curr-x curr-y)
  (let ((cxy (list (float curr-x) (float curr-y)))) ;; allocate just once!
    (nconc ;; destructive append: use with care
      (loop for y from 1 to 8
            when (/= y curr-y)
              append (list cxy (list (float curr-x) (float y))))
      (loop for x from 1 to 8
            when (/= x curr-x)
              append (list cxy (list (float x) (float curr-y)))))))
```